# PostgreSQL, aggregate and combine

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have a table in PostgreSQL:

```
name TEXT,
country_code TEXT
visited TIMESTAMP
```

I know `country_code` can only be `US`, `UK` or `CH`.

I would like an output similar to:

```
name,  US-last-visited, UK-last-visited, CH-last-visited
Gregg  null             2022-01-02       2001-01-02
Paul   1999-01-10       null             2021-01-03
```

Can that be done somewhat simple with e.g. `GROUP BY` and `ARRAY_AGG` or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select name
     , max(case when country_code = 'US' then visited end) as US_last_visited
     , max(case when country_code = 'UK' then visited end) as UK_last_visited
     , max(case when country_code = 'CH' then visited end) as CH_last_visited
from t
group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filtered aggregation:

```
select name, 
       max(visited) filter (where country_code = 'UK') as uk_last_visited,
       max(visited) filter (where country_code = 'US') as us_last_visited,
       max(visited) filter (where country_code = 'CH') as ch_last_visited
from the_table
group by name
```